# accept function doesn't wait for connection(doesn't block)

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple socket server in C and followed the tutorial in the book 'The Art Of Exploitation'

Every time I try to run the server, I get the output:

> Could not accept new connection

My C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(void) {
    // Declare initial values;
    int domain, sock_fd, type;
    struct sockaddr_in localAddr;
    socklen_t addr_length;
    ...
    sock_fd = socket(domain, type, 0);
    ...
    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &localAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))
    ...
    // Setup listening
    sock_fd = listen(sock_fd, 1);
    char buffer[1024];
    int sin_size, recv_len;
    while (1) {
        int client_fd;
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
        sin_size = sizeof(clientAddr);
        client_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) (&clientAddr), &sin_size);
        if (client_fd == -1) { <----------- HERE
            printf("Could not accept new connection");
            exit(-1);
        }   
        close(client_fd);
    }
    close(sock_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors and warnings given by the compiler for your code.

But I guess the deal-breaker was that you were doing,

```
 sock_fd = listen(sock_fd, 1);
```

which should be,

```
 listen(sock_fd, 1);
```

And that you were using the socket command with an uninitialized variable.

```
// sock_fd = socket(domain, type, 0); // wrong
(sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); // correct
```

The following settings were also missing,

```
// The following three lines were missing
localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
localAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
```

Here is the complete code with more fixes, which still has some warnings about unused variables, etc but at least it goes all way to "being ready for accepting connections."

You should really turn on all possible warnings on your compiler and read [Beej's network programming book](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(void) {
    // Declare initial values;
    int domain, sock_fd, type;
    struct sockaddr_in localAddr;

    // The following three lines were missing
    localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    localAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    socklen_t addr_length;

    // sock_fd = socket(domain, type, 0);
    //////////////////////Creating a SOCKET/////////////////////////
    if((sock_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1)
    {
        printf("ERROR:Socket failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &localAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR:Binding on server\n");
        close(sock_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    // Setup listening
    listen(sock_fd, 1);
    char buffer[1024];
    int sin_size, recv_len;
    while (1) {
        int client_fd;
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
        sin_size = sizeof(clientAddr);
        client_fd = accept(sock_fd, NULL, NULL);
        if (client_fd == -1) {
            printf("Could not accept new connection");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(client_fd);
    }
    close(sock_fd);
    return 0;
}
```